# A cyclic group having only one generator

Tags: group-theory

Please give an example of a cyclic group having only one generator. The only example I can think of is the trivial group, leading me to think I cannot find another example? If such a group doesn’t exist please state an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only nontrivial such group is $\mathbb{Z}_2$. That's because $g$ generates $\mathbb{Z}_n$ when $g$ and $n$ are relatively prime and that happens more than once for $n > 2$.

Answer (score 7):

Suppose $a$ generates $G$. Then so does $a^{-1}$. If $G$ has one and only one generator, that means that $a=a^{-1}$, hence $a^2=1$. Thus, $a$ has order $1$ or $2$, so $\langle a\rangle$ has order $1$ (the trivial group) or $2$ (cyclic group of order $2$). Both of those work. So those are the only two examples.